# Apex5.1, How to populate fields & region when select from drop-down list

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have page Item, when enter Id :P1_ID e.g 123456 it gives list Reference1, Reference2 in  :P2_REF

:P1_ID   set as TEXT field
:P2_REF  set as Select List
:P2_DESC set as Display only
:P2_Status set as Display only

How to populate :P2_DESC AND :P2_STATUS when reference1 is selected from the list of :P2_REF and also to refresh the region based on that value.
Ive created a sql statement.. would like to know how to call it.

Answer (score 0):

To populate :P2_DESC and :P2_STATUS you just need to create a Dynamic Action:

- **Event:** Change
- **Selection Type:** Item(s)
- **Item(s):** P2_REF

True Action:

- **Action:** Execute PL/SQL Code
- **plsql code:** select desc, status into :P2_DESC, :P2_STATUS from tbl where ref = :P2_REF
- **Items to Submit:** P2_REF
- **Items to return:** P2_DESC,P2_STATUS